# Split vector in equal parts, and avoid parts with single element

Tags: r

I need to split a vector in roughly equal parts.

Say I have:

```
part<-(1:12)
```

And i need to split this n times. where n=6:12

The following code works up to n=11.

```
split(x, ceiling(seq_along(x)/n))


When n=11, my result is

split(x, ceiling(seq_along(x)/11))

$`1`
[1] 10  3  4  1  3  5  6  7  9  2 11

$`2`
[1] 4
```

How do I avoid this?
I want a code which states that, if a list has a single value, this value will be assigned to the previous list

Comment: It is not clear what you wanted.  Did you meant `lapply(n, function(x) split(part, ceiling(seq_along(part)/x)))`

Comment: Hi, Sorry if am not clear.

I am new to both R and this forum.

If i split this function by
    lapply(11,function(x) split(part, ceiling(seq_along(part)/x)))
I end ut with two lists. One which contains the first 11 numbers, and one list which has 4 in it. Is there a command which ensures that, if a list is generated and has one single value, it will be assigned to the previous list.
In this case, this will lead to that both n=11 and n=12 will produce the same output.

Comment: `g <- cut(x, n, labels = FALSE); split(x, g)` will cut `x` into `n` roughly equal sized groups.  If n <= length(x)/2 then there will not be any singletons so modify `n` to be `n <- min(n, length(x)/2)` first. .